# How to clone a input field and copy its value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic form with input fields, the form has to be dynamic and therfore i choose to clone the input fields, the new fields dont hold any data, and if possible i want to copy the values from the orginal field.

**My htmlcode:**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-muted">Datepicker</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepick" name="from_date[]" value="Choose date">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed

    $(".add_field_button").click(function(e){

        fieldset_clone = add_button
            .closest('fieldset')
            .find('.fieldset-content')
            .eq(0)
            .clone();

        fieldset_clone.find('[name]')
                      .each(function(){
                          $(this).val($(this).prop('defaultValue'));
                      });

        fieldset_content = $('<div>')
            .addClass('fieldset-content')
            .append(fieldset_clone.children());             
    });
});
```

Comment: The HTML and JavaScript code that you are posting in the question doesn't hold any relation. The JavaScript is referencing elements that are not in the HTML (`.add_field_button`, `.fieldset-content`), and variables that are not defined (`add_button`), so it's not possible to know what the expected behavior/action is. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and provide a demo of the problem.

Comment: As a separate comment: what is really failing? Are the fields being cloned at all (I don't see them being appended to the page)? Or are they appended but just not with the right value?

Comment: The content are cloned but not the data filled in the fields.

Answer (score -1):

try to add `);` at the end of your function click.

Comment: coes works now, but dont copy the conent filled in the inputs.